# How to pass two string value in one href

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm trying to pass to argument in href in that employee_id pass correctly because i set session.getAttribute but when i tried to fetch 2nd value from result set nothing pass to in url here is my jsp code

```
<html>
<body>
      <table border="1" align="center" background="images\blue-wallpaper-7.jpg">
           <tr>
                 <td>PROJECT_NAME </td>
                <td>HEADER</td>
                <td>DESCRIPTION</td>
                <td> TASK_DATE</TD>
                <td>STATUS</td>
           </tr>
                <%

                  String employee_id=session.getAttribute("Employee_id").toString();
           Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
          Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.18.114.213:1821:godb","xe","se");
          Statement statement=con.createStatement();
          String sql="SELECT PROJECT_ID,Employee_id,PROJECT_NAME,HEADER,DESCRIPTION,TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TASK_DATE,'MM-DD-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YYYY') as TASK_DATE FROM EMPLOYEE_TASK WHERE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TASK_DATE,'MM-DD-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YYYY')>=(SYSDATE)-7 and employee_id='"+employee_id+"' order by project_id asc";
          ResultSet resultset=statement.executeQuery(sql);

while(resultset.next())
{

String PROJECT_ID=resultset.getString("PROJECT_ID");
 /*out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
 out.write("alert('You are successfully Logout at :" + PROJECT_ID + "')");
   out.println("</script>");*/
                %>
                <tr>

                 <td><%=resultset.getString("PROJECT_NAME")%></td>
              <td><%=resultset.getString("HEADER")%></td>
              <td><%=resultset.getString("DESCRIPTION")%></td>
              <td><%=resultset.getString("TASK_DATE")%></td>
               <td>
          <a href="update_employeetask.jsp?id=<%=resultset.getString("Employee_id")%>&PROJECT_ID_update="<%=PROJECT_ID%>>update</a> // here i want to pass Project_id this i id will fetch request.getparameter from another page 
           <a href="update_employeetask.jsp?id=<%=resultset.getString("Employee_id")%>&PROJECT_ID_delete="<%=PROJECT_ID%>>Delete</a>

            </td>

                </tr>
                <%
                }
                %>


            </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your question does not make sense. Not good english and no use of punctuation. Please can you update

Comment: open your console to check the link, it looks like you have a typo error, it should be :`<a href="update_employeetask.jsp?id=<%=resultset.getString("Employee_id")%>&PROJECT_ID_update=<%=PROJECT_ID%>">`

Comment: @scraaappy: thank you its working properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution suggested by scaraapy works properly.

```
<a href="update_employeetask.jsp?id=<%=resultset.getString("Employee_id")%>&PROJECT_ID_update=<%=PROJECT_ID%>">
```